# React state manipulation through spread operator

Tags: reactjs

I have this initial state:

```
this.state = {
    formInfo: {
        name: '',
        age: '',
        height: ''
    },
    errorMessage: ''
}
```

When editing the form, the state should update and this is how I'm handling this at the moment:

```
handleInputChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        formInfo: {
            ...this.state.formInfo,
            [name]: value
        }
    })
}
```

Can you provide me of a better solution to manipulate the state, in case this process does not follow the industry standards?

I doubt if there's a more efficient way to archive this.

Comment: If you are concerned with dealing with objects much more complicated than your example, you could look into immer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about best practice then below is the one. Your code was fine. Only better to avoid dot notation's and provide default values.

```
handleInputChange = e => {
  const {
    target: {
      name = '',
      value = '',
    } = {},
  } = e;

  const {
    formInfo,
  } = this.state;

  this.setState({
    formInfo: {
      ...formInfo,
      [name]: value,
    },
  });
}
```